# I can't install kivy

Tags: installation, pip, kivy

the error occurs after the command: pip

PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [13 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5

```
  [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3 -> 22.3.1
  [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
  [end of output]
```

PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (65.5.0)
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
Attempting uninstall: setuptools
Found existing installation: setuptools 65.5.0
Uninstalling setuptools-65.5.0:
Successfully uninstalled setuptools-65.5.0
Successfully installed setuptools-65.6.3 wheel-0.38.4
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip3 install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.38.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (65.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> python -m pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.38.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (65.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> python3 -m pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
Python nπo encontrado; execute sem argumentos para instalar na Microsoft Store ou desabilite este atalho a partir de Configuraτ⌡es > Gerenciar Aliases de Execuτπo do Aplicativo.
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> py -m pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (0.38.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (65.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\nilkn\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (22.3.1)
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [10 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip install pip==21.3.1
Collecting pip==21.3.1
Downloading pip-21.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.7/1.7 MB 3.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
C:\Users\Nilkn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m pip install pip==21.3.1
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> uninstall pip
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip uninstall kivy
WARNING: Skipping kivy as it is not installed.
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [10 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting wheel
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL> pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [10 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
PS C:\Users\Nilkn\Dropbox\My PC (FranklinSoul)\Desktop\appPython\FKL>

```
I use the latest version of Python on windows 11, and I can't install kivy
```

Comment: "Kivy 2.1.0 officially supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.10." from the getting started / installation page.  it will help if you edit your post to be more concise and explain the steps.  you will most likely want to download the Windows Installer (64-bit) from this page: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3108/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not supported for Python 3.11 .

Comment: Comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me.

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```